# Run service frequently also after app was closed

Tags: java, android, android-service

For my app I want to fetch data from a server in the background. When the user wants to be notified about specific changes, I want my app to keep fetching data even when the app was closed. I was researching about this topic and found out that the possibilities of running services continuously also  after the app is closed changed with Android Oreo. What I don‘t see are the alternatives to handle running services in background with newer versions of android. The most proposed solution I saw is using a Foreground Service. But since I don‘t have any user interaction, I don‘t think this solution fits perfectly. Also I read about the WorkManager but unfortunately it has a minimum time interval of 15 minutes. Are there other alternatives to process data in the background continuously than a Foreground service and a WorkManager?

Comment: I understand it as you want to poll your server in the background and fetch and process that data if there is any changes? In that case, you will have to do with the WorkManagers restriction of 15 minute intervals. Another (and better) approach would be to let your server notify the client about changes via push messages (think Firebase Cloud Messaging). This message would wake up your app briefly but long enough to fetch the latest data from your API.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need "user interaction" to have a Foreground Service, what you need is a Notification that cannot be removed while the service is in foreground.

If your notification Context is the service itself, tapping on the notification will take the user to the "settings" where he/she can force close the service for example).

You can start your FG service in a BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receiver. You have to quickly (5 seconds or less) send it to Foreground or android will throw an exception. Unfortunately, [there's a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76112072) which Google thinks it's ok and closed as "won't fix" but you'll still need to work around.

Long story short, have an onCreate in your service:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        final Notification notification = createNotification();
        startForeground("SOME_UNIQUE_ID", notification);
    }
```

You get the idea (the `createNotification()` is whatever you want to create a Channel (if O+) + Notification.

HOWEVER, all this is nice, but it will have a service running all the time, which is probably not what you should do.

You can use an Alarm a trigger a more efficient (in terms of scope) Intent Service to do the job, schedule another alarm in, say 5 minutes, and do it again.

Or -as commented- you could use Firebase, and Notifications to react to a change.

All in all, those are the options.

I'd say that unless you truly need "real time" updating, the 15 ~ of WorkManager is usually fine, if you can deal with the fact that you have to design your code to be very independent, because WorkManager cannot receive much information and it's a pain to use for some things...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Is the notification required to do anything, or can it have no effect as well, do you know that? Also the Foreground Service is useable for all android versions, is that correct?

Comment: The notification doesn't need to "do" anything. You can provide an icon, a Title, and "content". If you *do not* provide an icon, the title and content won't properly display ("by design"), but other than that, the notification doesn't need to do anything else other than show up... which you cannot avoid to begin with.  Foreground Services have been around for a while, and are available to old API levels. You should read the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) for services to make sure you understand what's needed.

Comment: Okay I understand. Now I‘m using a service that runs in the background while the app is opened. When the app is closed now do I have to stop the background service and start a foreground service and vice versa when the app is started again, or is there another more recommendable way to keep the service being executed?

Comment: A service can be promoted to Foreground (and back to Background) without the need to restart it. There many ways to approach this, one is to pass an intent to the service and pass some key/value (e.g.: key: SEND_TO_FG, value: true) and in your `onStartCommand(...)` check for this flag and call: `startForeground(notification)` or `stopForeground(true)` `//true = remove notification, false = keep it)` An Activity can signal the service to do the same thing; all this is available in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to solve it with your advice! I have one last question about the general understanding of a foreground service. When the service is started and the app gets closed, is then only the service kept alive and all the activities are killed, or is the whole app still running with all its functionalities then?